# Sort of solved - Working my way through the donut tutorial, made a big mistake during the geometry nodes section. Is is salvageable?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I hope this question will be welcomed here from a true beginner. It's a very specific problem, and I have a suspicion that I know the answer. But I'm new enough to know that I know absolutely nothing, so I want to try every avenue before giving up and starting this section over.

I'm on part 9 of the Blender Guru donut tutorial - geometry nodes. The good news: everything has been going swimmingly so far. I've started the tutorial over several times to reinforce the concepts and have enjoyed the process despite some minor setbacks.

This step is the furthest I've gotten - my render looked awesome at the end of the tutorial video, I was feeling confident, then I realized...I had somehow inadvertently deleted the sprinkle that I had used to model over the surface of the donut.

It's gone.

In the beginning of the next part of the tutorial (Number 10, Random Color Tutorial), Andrew goes over editing this particular sprinkle to complete the rest of the project.

Am I boned? Is there any way to recover this sprinkle, or to edit the multi-sprinkle mesh that now covers my donut? Do I have to delete all of my geometry node progress and start over with a brand new starter sprinkle?

I am including 2 screenshots of my donut (with and without my beloved sprinkle) and a timestamped link to the tutorial in the hopes that it will help. The first features a concept render which features the lost sprinkle. It is unknown as to when I deleted it, but as is evident from the second image, it is no longer with us. Any insight is appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ?t=652

[image: withspronkle]

[image: withoutspronkle]

[image: viewer and node layout]

[image: sprinkle attack]

Comment: We can't tell what's going on just by looking at the donut, a full screenshot of the file, showing the Outliner (to see what objects you have) and your Geo Nodes setup would be more helpful. If you simply deleted the sprinkle, you don't really need to start over since your GeoNodes setup should still be live on the donut, waiting for a sprinkle to distribute. Make a new sprinkle and use its Object Info in that setup and it should sort itself out.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'm looking into the geo node layout now and trying to decipher what you mean about adding a full screenshot of the file. I'll update my post with a screenshot of my node setup in the meantime. I'm encouraged by reading your final line about making a new sprinkle and using the object info.

Comment: What you added is what I meant with full screenshot: a shot of your whole screen, showing all objects and setups. Like I said, your geometry nodes is already there. You seem to be distributing a "Cylinder", but it doesn't show in the Outliner (the list of objects on the top-right), that can either be because it's deleted, or it's parented to another object. If it's deleted, simply make another one, and choose the new object from the dropdown in the "Object Info" node in your setup.

Comment: Aha! This certainly did something. Not what I had in mind, exactly, but you absolutely set me on the right path. I'm going to play around with the node system and treat this whole thing as a learning experience. If anyone's curious, I'm going to post a screenshot of what your fix did to my donut.Thank you, Kuboå!

Answer (score 3):

Solved by the user Kuboa in the comments above, and with a little tweaking of the existing nodes. I encountered the big crispy ball in the final screenshot by accidentally not applying the scale to the new cylinder - once I did, it resolved itself no problem.

Comment: Thank you! Just changing the scale on "Instance on Points", solved it!